# Apple Watch app detect if a apple watch is paired with the phone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, watchkit

When the user opens the app on the phone is there a way to detect if the phone is paired/connected to a apple watch?

Comment: Your question title and question content are contradicts to each other. In title, you are asking `can we detect from an apple watch app that the watch is paired with an iPhone or not` and in the question content its completely reversed that - `can we detect from an iPhone app that the phone is paired/connected to an apple watch`. I think, you should consider updating this question title as you've already received the answer which are related to question contents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in method (at least in the WatchKit SDK) to determine if a Watch has been paired with an iPhone. A common strategy is to write a BOOL to a shared NSUserDefaults (using app groups) so that the iPhone knows that the Watch app has been run at least once. That's the technique I've used in my own app.

Comment: Using a boolean in the NSUserDefaults wouldn't work with proper user on boarding. For example, if you need extra permissions for your Watch app, you don't want to ask that to everyone. However, you also do not want to force people to open your Watch App, read that it isn't usable until they open the iPhone app and then ask for permissions. @bilalreffas answer is pretty good.

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no other method in WatchOS 1. WatchOS 2 has introduced new functionality that supersedes my answer.

Answer (score 25):

So on WatchOS 2 that is possible !

You have to do on iPhone side :

First :

```
import WatchConnectivity
```

Then :

```
   if WCSession.isSupported() { // check if the device support to handle an Apple Watch
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession() // activate the session

        if session.paired { // Check if the iPhone is paired with the Apple Watch
                // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

I hope It would help you :)

Comment: You shouldn't comment on other's answer in your own answer. "To add a boolean to the share defaults to check if the iPhone is Paired it's not a great solution." Do that as a comment on the actual answer, since that keeps the conversation clear.

Comment: Will this statement return true even if my app doesn't have anything to do with the Apple Watch?

Comment: I tested it now, and it works. However, the watch will get a message to trust/accept the application. If the goal is to simply check if there is an AppleWatch, that seems a bit harsh. On the other hand, the if-statement `if session.paired` is returning true before the user gets the dialog on the watch, so it doesn't matter if the user accepts the app or not.

Answer (score 1):

If your code in your extension runs willActivate: on you controller then the Apple Watch is paired with the phone.  Since you can't run any code on the actual Apple Watch there is no to know if the watch isn't paired with an iPhone.

Comment: Can I display an UI to let the user know that his watch is not paired to his iPhone? In my finding - if an apple watch is not paired with an iPhone then it won't shows any UI element and will simply show a black screen. Did you handle this case?