# Detecting Apple Watch in iOS 8

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have some events that should only be fired off if a user has an Apple Watch.  Is there a way to detect whether a watch is paired?  I'm not sure if I can use the shared app group to detect the Apple Watch extension or maybe I can use bluetooth?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661252/apple-watch-app-detect-if-a-apple-watch-is-paired-with-the-phone/29662068#29662068

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you an do is set a BOOL to true in shared NSUserDefaults the first time the Watch app is run and then check for that value in your iOS app. All indications on the dev forums and publicly have been that there isn't a way to programatically know if a Watch has been paired.

Comment: Man that's a bummer.  The only way you really know then is if the user launches the watch app.

Comment: Unless something has changed very recently, I believe so yes.

Comment: You can now check if a watch is paired using Watch Connectivity Framework

Answer (score 1):

This is possible on watchOS2.0+

I tried to give an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190804/2946782

you can check if connectivity session is supported as described here: [How to check whether iPhone and apple watch are connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793093/how-to-check-whether-iphone-and-apple-watch-are-connected)