# How to track how many users are using Apple Watch

Tags: ios, analytics, apple-watch

is there a way to track how many iOS-users do have (and use) an Apple Watch as well? Is it tracked via Google Analytics automatically or what do I have to do to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean how many of the users of your iOS app also installed the Watch functions that it has?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681458/detecting-apple-watch-in-ios-8) answer yours.

> The best you an do is set a BOOL to true in shared NSUserDefaults the first time the Watch app is run and then check for that value in your iOS app. All indications on the dev forums and publicly have been that there isn't a way to programatically know if a Watch has been paired.